# PHP Regex Help / Explanation

Tags: php, regex

Up until now I have successfully managed to avoid doing very much with regular expressions apart from checking an email address is valid. However, as part of a larger university project I'm developing a simple tempting engine and am trying to implement my own simple syntax for handling loops, and eventually IF statements rather than including PHP in my template files. I know a lot of people will say don't bother or just use an existing system, but as it's for my dissertation I want as much of it to be my own work as possible!

Anyway, back to the problem. I've got the following code in a my template file as an example:

```
<p>Template Header</p>
{{foreach{array1}}}
    <p>This is the first content line that should be displayed.</p>
{{/foreach}}
{{foreach{array2}}}
    <p>This is the second content line that should be displayed.</p>
{{/foreach}}
<p>Template Footer</p>
```

I've then got the following PHP to read the file, look for loops and extract them.

```
<?php
$template = file_get_contents('reg.html');
$expression = "#.*{{foreach{(.*?)}}}(.*?){{/foreach}}.*#is";
$result = preg_replace($expression, "$1", $template);  
var_dump($result);
?>
```

When calling preg_replace and dumping the result $1 is giving me the array name which will be used for the loop (array1 or array2), then changing it to $2 will give me the content between the loop tags. Perfect. The problem is it only works for one {{foreach}} tag.

Is there anyway I can loop all matches of the regex to get the results I'm getting above? ANy help / advice is much appreciated - but go easy regex is pretty new to me!

Comment: This is *not* a suitable task for regular expressions. You will have a *brutal* time as soon as you attempt to nest `foreach` or `if` blocks. You need to write a real parser, not cobble something together by abusing regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
$expression = "#.*{{foreach{(.*?)}}}(.*?){{/foreach}}.*#is";
                ^^                                   ^^
```

You are not just matching the "foreach" template tag, but also everything before and after it. That means the second foreach will get eaten up by `.*` too. So you can't match it again.

Comment: You might add that specifically, the match will match the entire string if it contains one of these `foreach` blocks, and then _replace_ the entire string with the contents of the `foreach` block. That is, _replaced_, not just eaten up.